# SQLite multi row export

Tags: mysql, sqlite, dump

I dumped a SQLite database to a .sql file. However, there are about 800 inserts and importing it takes a lot of time. Like a minute or two.

Is there a way to dump the data with multi-row inserts so the import could be faster, similar to the mysql extended inserts?

I have to use the Windows sqlite3.exe command tool.

Or I need a faster import command than `sqlite3.exe db.dat < file.sql`

Comment: sqlite database is a single file. Why not just copy the file?

Comment: It's complicated. I need to do it the way I explained it or I need a faster import command than sqlite3.exe db.dat < file.sql

Comment: Can you explain why copying / reading the copied file doesn't work?  sqlite database files are very portable and dumping to a script only to reimport using sqlite is wasteful.

Comment: I had multiple databases, and a single SQL file exported from another place needed to be imported in all the databases on a regular basis. I already created a batch import script, however I didn't know how to speed up the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the exported sql.file and wrap the sql insert statements into a single transaction.

begin

... (inserts) ...

commit

For more information see http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: Magic. Thanks a lot! You were the first one to answer so you get the tick.

Answer (score 1):

800 inserts is not very much, two minutes sounds like a lot.

However, the most common issue with slow inserts in SQLite is that you're not wrapping them inside a transaction so that an implicit transaction is generated for each insert.  This slows SQlite from potentially 50,000 inserts per second to "a few dozen" per second. See [this FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

To fix this, add BEGIN at the beginning of your .sql file and COMMIT at the end.

Comment: Both of you gave me very helpful answers. Indeed, the transaction did a miracle. Your answer was second, but more complete. However, you already have enough reputation so I'm gonna give the other guy the "Best answer" award :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help (although, just to be strictly accurate, my answer shows in my browser as a minute before kjtl ;-)).

Comment: My browser went crazy, then. It showed that his answer was 2 minutes before yours, now it shows yours first. Anyway, I think it's a good welcome for him like it was for me on other StackExchange websites and I hope you don't mind (-;

Comment: No, as I said -- no worries.  It's nice to think of the new participant and, contrary to what we've all been told, it turns out you can't trade the points in at Starbucks. . .